# Drawing arbitrary lines with EaselJS

Tags: line, easeljs

I need to connect two items graphically. Which is the best way to draw an arbitrary line between two objects using EaselJS? Is it possible to make something like magnet lines that are attached to the closest object?

Would you have any example of that?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest/quickest way would probably be to use a Shape and use `moveTo()` with the coordinates of the first object and then `lineTo()` with the coordinates of the second object. And whenever the objects move you clear that and redraw the line.
Performance wise I cannot really say if this is the best way, but if it's not too many lines and desktop only I wouldn't worry about that, you should be fine then.

Another option would be to use a bitmap, that contains a line and scale+rotate it to the correct length/angle, this comes probably more handy if you want your line to be 'fancy' in any way and it would be too difficult to draw with a shape.

Comment: Both approaches seems good to me, but I think that I'll not redraw the line because it could be used on mobile devices.

Just a question related to the first way, is there any way to check if the line between two points collides with a third object?

Comment: sure, Method 1) The (probably) best performing way: meassure the distance from obj3 to the line: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line and if it is below a certain threshold(the width/height of obj3) you then have to check if it lies between obj1 and obj2, if so, then it intersercts. **or** Method 2) (little more accurate) Calc the bounds of obj3 and use a line-line check for each side of that rect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection , additionally you'd have to check if one of the intersecting points lies between obj1+2

Comment: or Method 3) The worst performing but easy and pixel-perfect method (only works with bitmaps and **not** with shapes) You place the line, then do a pixel-collision-check( https://github.com/olsn/Collision-Detection-for-EaselJS ) and then do your actions if they collide.

Comment: Redrawing the line makes the most sense, even in Mobile environments. In order to update the stage, the entire canvas is redrawn, so creating new instructions for a Shape will have an almost immeasurable effect. Remember to clear your graphics each time, or the instructions will add up each time!